# Want to read an a file and write to existing excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, text-files

[enter image description here][1]I have a text file with data delimited qith a pipe delimiter, i want to write it to an excel sheet.

I have created a code but it is taking around 700 seconds to execute since the data in the input file is large(about 45kb).
Is there any way to optimize it?

Thanks

Please find the code as follows:

```
import csv
from time import process_time


def create_sheet():
    wb1 = Workbook()
    wb1.create_sheet("A")
    wb1.create_sheet("B")
    src_sheet = wb1.create_sheet("C")
    print(type(src_sheet))
    wb1.create_sheet("D")
    sheet = wb1['Sheet']
    wb1.remove(sheet)
    write_Data(src_sheet)
    wb1.save('outfile.xlsx')


def write_Data(src_sheet):
    csv.register_dialect('myDialect', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    data_list = []
    with open("C:/Users/atapadar/input_text.txt",
              "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='myDialect')
        count: int = 1
        for i in reader:
            if count == 1:
                i.append("New col")
            else:
                i.append(i[0] + i[1] + i[3])
            count = count + 1
            src_sheet.append(i)



t1_start = process_time()

create_sheet()

t1_stop = process_time()
print("Elapsed time during the whole program in seconds:", t1_stop - t1_start)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9iMQ.png
```

Comment: I am not even sure this code will write any data to the excel file

Comment: Please provide a sample csv file and the output of the excel sheet where you were able to write to it in 700 secs

Comment: sample data

`96|05|5|02|F|3|89|P| |AG|AFL|12|20201016|          1 |West      |HO|CALIFORNIA - BAY    |RENT
74|08|1|02|F|1|22|E| |AG|AFO|12|20201016|          6 |Eastern   |PR|                    |HO3
14|08|2|02|F|1|29|S| |AG|AFO|12|20201016|          3 |Central   |HO|                    |SPHO
14|08|2|02|F|3|29|P| |AG|AFO|12|20201016|          1 |Central   |HO|                    |TC
14|08|2|02|F|1|32|S| |AG|AFO|12|20201016|          3 |Central   |HO|                    |NGHO
07|08|3|02|F|3|66|P| |WC|AFL|12|20201016|          2 |Central   |HO|                    |TC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this via dataframes would be much simpler:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", sep="|")
df['New col'] = int(df['C1']) + int(df['C2']) + int(df['C3'])

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```